# setting intent on search results

Tags: android, arrays

here Heloo guys im working on an app with auto suggestion and search the problem is when i type a letter in the searchfield and the suggestion changes still the items in the search launches the same intents according to ther position and not the actual intended synonym class how can i set specific intent on the search entries such that even if the position changes still the same activity is launched by a diffrent search entry whose name corresponds with the search result
[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hk85G.jpg)
[second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgdVQ.jpg)

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the search menu action bar.
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);

    // Get the search menu.
    MenuItem searchMenu = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_menu_search);

    searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenu);
    mSearchAutoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
    mSearchAutoComplete.setThreshold(0);
    mSearchAutoComplete.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.tabcolor));
    mSearchAutoComplete.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    mSearchAutoComplete.setDropDownBackgroundResource(android.R.color.darker_gray);

    /* Create a new ArrayAdapter and add data to search auto complete object.
   how can i set each word when onclicked to open the corresponding class no matter the position
    */
    String dataArr[] = {"Kiambu county", "Kisumu county", "Kitui county", "Laikipia county", "Lamu county", "Meru county", "Mombasa county", "Muranga county", "Nairobi county", "Nakuru county", "Narok county", "kajiado county", "Uansingishu county", "Makueni County", "Machakos county"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> newsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, dataArr);
    mSearchAutoComplete.setAdapter(newsAdapter);

    // Listen to search view item on click event.
    mSearchAutoComplete.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            if (i == 0) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Kiambu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Kisumu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 2) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Kitui.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 3) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Laikipia.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 4) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Lamu.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 5) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Meru.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 6) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Mombasa.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 7) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Muranga.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 8) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Nairobi.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 9) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Nakuru.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 10) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Narok.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 11) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Kajiado.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 12) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Singishu                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                .class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 13) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Makueni.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
            if (i == 14) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Machakos.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });



    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

help out im really stuck

Comment: I am sorry could you specify the problem again

Comment: You should use setOnItemSelectedListener instead

Comment: @KevinKurien all search results open the same activity even if the search keyword is diffrent

Comment: try @Firoz Memon answer . it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have added condition base on `i` which gives the current position of adapter item clicked.

So, when you search something, it filters the data and displays it accordingly, and when you click on say 1st item, it will always open `Kiambu` class.

You need to update your condition inside your `onItemClick` method to something like:

```
        if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[0])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Kiambu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[1])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Kisumu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[2])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Kitui.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[3])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Laikipia.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[4])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Lamu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[5])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Meru.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[6])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Mombasa.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[7])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Muranga.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[8])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Nairobi.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[9])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Nakuru.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[10])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Narok.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[11])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Kajiado.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[12])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Singishu.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[13])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Makueni.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else if (newsadapter.getItem(i).equals(dataArr[14])) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(County.this, Machakos.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```